# webview not refreshing data after logged

Tags: javascript, html, electron

We have a Electron application with a webview. This webview connects to a website where we have to log in.
This website creates download files with a token. This token are working X time.

The issue is: The token are never "changing " when we come from webview and download files are not working past X time. Even if you log out and log in.

If you access to the website with Firefox, Chrome etc.. tokens are working properly.

Comment: Could you add some code how you create the webview?

Comment: yes, it's a simple webview. <webview style="height: 600px;" src="URL"></webview>

Comment: SOLVED: The problem was that the userAgent had to be the same one.